# SQL: GROUP BY Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    (1.0*( SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume)
           FROM
               RawData r
               INNER JOIN Product p
                   ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
           WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER')
           GROUP BY p.Distributor
         )
         /
         ( SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume)
           FROM RawData r
         )*100)
    ;
```

The query above leads to an error:

> Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Is the issue with the GROUP BY Clause? Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Table structure of RawData?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of your query is the problem:

```
SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER') GROUP BY p.Distributor
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are Grouping BY p.Distributor and there could possibly be two of those based on your where clause. `WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER')`. You can take the group by out and it will have a total `SUM` of both `TF1` and `WARNER`

```
SELECT
(1.0 * (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r
        INNER JOIN Product p ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
        WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER')
) / (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r)*100);
```

If you are meaning to get a percentage of sales volume by distributor you should use this instead.

```
SELECT p.Distributor, SUM(r.SalesVolume) as Sales, ROUND((SUM(r.SalesVolume) / (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r) * 100), 1) as percentOfTotal
FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER')
GROUP BY p.Distributor
```

I suggest using the [ROUND function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) here. The above query rounds to a single digit after the decimal point. If you want two digits use this:

```
ROUND((SUM(r.SalesVolume) / (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) FROM RawData r) * 100), 2) as percentOfTotal
```

Comment: You sir, are amazing. I am however confused with the `CAST`. I need the result to be something like 12.2 In this case how would i change the precision?

Comment: The cast is to convert the `SUM` value to a `decimal` so that SQL will do decimal division, not integer division. It works similar to multiplying the value by `1.0` except you can explicitly define the precision. `14,4` would allow for 4 digits after the decimal point. You can refine this as needed to suit your needs. If you only want 1 after you can use `17,1` but you should consider use of the `ROUND` function to avoid accidental precision loss.

Comment: My result set is `Distributor Sales MarketShares
WARNER 2836192 58.131470300744400
TF1 268668 5.506702600797200` And any change in the precision is giving me an arithmetic flow error.

Comment: I see, i did not know those were decimal fields. Updating my answer, and will include use of the `ROUND` function.

Comment: `Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments.` Never used the round function before though

Answer (score 0):

Your correlated query:

```
SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume) 
FROM RawData r
INNER JOIN Product p
    ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE p.Distributor in ('TF1','WARNER')
GROUP BY p.Distributor)
```

Will return a row for each group, i.e. one for TF1, one for WARNER.

You need to not group by any field that will lead to multiple rows

Comment: The result I am looking at is two rows with one for `Warner` and one for `TF1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN p.distributor IN ('TF1', 'WARNER') THEN rawData END), 0) * 100.0 / SUM(rawData)
FROM    rawData r
LEFT JOIN
        product p
USING   (productId)
```